# Blueimp jQuery File Uploader and save filesize into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload, blueimp

i use Blueimp jQuery File Uploader and  i want to update user's **disk space used** by getting filesize of each file including filesize of thumbnail (if file is image) in database.
i noticed that each file, sends separate request to server so there will be mysql_query for each file.

1. first of all: where to put the mysql_query
2. 2nd: is it ok to run a update query foreach file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who have same question, i found the solution ,first of all you need to add query functions as said here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases

then
change

```
        if (is_int($img_width)) {
            $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
        }
```

to
this

```
        if (is_int($img_width)) {
            $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
        }else
    {
    $file->upload_to_db = $this->update_plus($file_size);//custom query function
```

and then search for *handle_image_file* function and add this *$filesize = 0;* at the beginning and
add following code at the end of the function

```
    $dir = 'yourBaseDir';
    if($file->url) $filesize += filesize(urldecode($dir.$file->url));
    if($file->thumbnail_url) $filesize += filesize(urldecode($dir.$file->thumbnail_url));
    $file->upload_to_db = $this->update_plus($filesize);
}
```

for deleting i use custom function separate of uploader

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried github wiki of Blueimp jquery file Uploader .

Here is link https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases

It tells you how to use database with uploader and you have to add your database updating code

in UploadHandler.php because on every single upload this uploader send XML request to server,

and Classes defined in UploadHandler.php in server/php folder is used.

Also in protected function handle_file_upload there is defined size variable which will be used in your mysql query.

```
$file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($size));
```

Rest you can do yourself via link i gave to you.

Comment: yes i did that already, My problem is that i can not capture filesize of thumbnail and i really dont think that running query foreach file upload is good idea

Comment: @h0mayun you will be querying once for every xml request.So there should not be problem.